# Convert jQuery to work with prototype

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I have the following jQuery code which I like to convert to work with prototype.

P.S. OMG! Your post does not have much context to explain the code sections; please explain your scenario more clearly.

```js
$(function() {

    // Set up variables
    var $el, $parentWrap, $otherWrap, 
        $allTitles = $("dt").css({
            padding: 5, // setting the padding here prevents a weird situation, where it would start animating at 0 padding instead of 5
            "cursor": "pointer" // make it seem clickable
        }),
        $allCells = $("dd").css({
            position: "relative",
            top: -1,
            left: 0,
            display: "none" // info cells are just kicked off the page with CSS (for accessibility)
        });

    // clicking image of inactive column just opens column, doesn't go to link   
    $("#page-wrap").delegate("a.image","click", function(e) { 

        if ( !$(this).parent().hasClass("curCol") ) {         
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $(this).next().find('dt:first').click(); 
        } 

    });

    // clicking on titles does stuff
    $("#page-wrap").delegate("dt", "click", function() {

        // cache this, as always, is good form
        $el = $(this);

        // if this is already the active cell, don't do anything
        if (!$el.hasClass("current")) {

            $parentWrap = $el.parent().parent();
            $otherWraps = $(".info-col").not($parentWrap);

            // remove current cell from selection of all cells
            $allTitles = $("dt").not(this);

            // close all info cells
            $allCells.slideUp();

            // return all titles (except current one) to normal size
            $allTitles.animate({
                fontSize: "14px",
                paddingTop: 0,
                paddingRight: 0,
                paddingBottom: 0,
                paddingLeft: 0
            });

            // animate current title to larger size            
            $el.animate({
                "font-size": "20px",
                paddingTop: 0,
                paddingRight: 0,
                paddingBottom: 0,
                paddingLeft: 0
            }).next().slideDown();

            // make the current column the large size
            $parentWrap.animate({
                width: 320
            }).addClass("curCol");

            // make other columns the small size
            $otherWraps.animate({
                width: 128
            }).removeClass("curCol");

            // make sure the correct column is current
            $allTitles.removeClass("current");
            $el.addClass("current");  

        }

    });

    $("#starter").trigger("click");

});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your question is unclear and your code already appears to be written using jQuery...

Comment: you are using jquery, what exactly are you trying to achieve??

Comment: This code doesn't work with prototype

Comment: @KrzysztofAdamski - you mean you want to convert it to work with prototype?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use both Prototype and jQuery you can use [jQuery's no confilct](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) which reassigns the use of the `$` variable back to Prototype and you can use both on the same website.

Comment: then i must use: `jQuery.noConflict(); (function($) {` before code and `})(jQuery);` on end of code?

Comment: you should use noConflict immediately after you load the jQuery library. then in your code make sure you use whatever you assigned the jquery variable to instead of $. e.g. $j = jQuery.nocConflict() then you have to use $j instead of $ when using jquery.